# How to change the position of AppBarLayout in CoordinatorLayout in Android Studio

Tags: android

[image]

I want to put the AppBarLayout on the bottom of the layout, but I cannot manually move it down since it is fixed on the top.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/holo_green_light" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

Here is how the xml code looks like. What do I have to adjust to change the position to the bottom?

Comment: Design wise, I cannot understand the rational of keeping your layout at the bottom of the screen. That defeats the purpose. I will recommend looking up tutorials and official documentation for `BottomNavigationView`.

Answer (score 0):

In the xml code you posted the parent element is not shown.
You can use a LinearLayout with orientation=vertical.

```
<LinearLayout
   ...
   orientation="vertical">

   VERY IMPORTANT TO PUT FIRST THE VIEW PAGER       
   <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    .../>



   <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    ...>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        .../>

  </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

Or if you do not want to use a LinearLayout, you can always use a a RelativeLayout and adding android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" in the AppBar.

But as @codeFreak says in the comment, I also recommend using BottomNavigationView for this.